# How to change a set element?

Tags: c++, set, const-iterator

I want to change the element in a `set`, so I used `set<T>::iterator`. However, the compiler argues "the element is const". Then I realized that `set<T>::iterator` is a `const_iterator`...

So, how I can change the element? Erase it and then insert a new one?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The elements of the `set` will be in sorted order. If you are allowed to modify an element, then this sorting order can not be maintained. Hence you can not modify the item. You need to erase the existing element and insert a new one.

Comment: It should be mentioned, though, that some changes to an element do not affect how it's sorted. If you want to make a change that you are sure does not impact the sorting order, there is always `const_cast` as a last resort. Risky and not beautiful, but nevertheless.

Comment: thanks.I know that . So this is the only way to modify the element?

Comment: Since `erase` doesn't throw unless the user code it calls throws, it's probably better to insert the new element and then erase the old one. That gives you a chance of the strong exception guarantee.

Comment: std::unordered_set ..first time to hear that

Answer (score 1):

Set elements are constant and may not be modified in place. Modification could change the ordering predicate without changing the position of the element which would violate the constraints of the data structure.

However now in the future (C++17), modifying the element without erasure is possible with the `extract` member function:

```
std::set<std::string> stringset{"a", "b", "c"};
auto node = stringset.extract(stringset.begin());
std::string& str = node.value();
str = "d";
stringset.insert(std::move(node));
```

There is still the cost of list operations but the object itself is not destroyed or copied.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: You cant add an element to a specific location in set. the set should be in the sorted order whatever operations you do. So you have to erase the specific element and insert the new element so that the ordering of set isnt lost.

Also read more about [set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/)!