# C++ pointer pointing to const object that was never made const

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I have a set of Students and an iterator which finds a specific student which I then need to change. The problem is, when I go to change the object the pointer points to, it says the object is const. I'm not sure why this is, as I do not think I ever explicitly make the objects constant. I am relatively new to C++, so I may be doing something to make the Student objects const accidentally.

Here is the main funcion

```
set<Student> students;
ifstream file(*somefilename*);
while (!file.is_open())
{
    cout << filename << endl;
    cout << "Could not open file. Enter new filename: ";
    cin >> filename;
    file.open(filename);
}

while (!file.eof()) {
    string temp = "";
    string name;
    int regNo;
    if (file.eof())break;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (i == 0)
            file >> regNo;
        else {
            file >> temp;
            name += temp;
        }
    }
    cout << "For loop done" << endl;
    students.insert(Student(name, regNo));
}

file.close();

file.open("ex1/marks.txt");

while(!file.eof()){
    int regNo;
    string module;
    int mark;
    file >> regNo;
    Student tempStud("",regNo);
    file >> module;
    file >> mark;
    set<Student>::iterator it = students.find(tempStud);
    if (it != students.end()) {
        **it->addMark(module, mark);**//here's the problem code
    }
}

file.close();

for (set<Student>::iterator it = students.begin(); it != students.end(); it++)
    cout << *it << endl;

cin.get();}
```

And here is the header file for the Student class

```
    public:
       Student(const string &name, int regNo);

    int getRegNo() const;

    void addMark(string& module, float mark);

    float getMark(const string &module) const;

    float getMin() const;

    float getMax() const;

    float getAvg() const;

    bool operator <(const Student& s2) const;

    bool operator >(const Student& s2);

    bool operator ==(const Student& s2);

private:
    int regNo;
    map<string, float> marks;  // keys are modules, values are marks in range 0.0 to 100.0
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &str, const Student &s);
```

Comment: On what line is the error occurring?  What exactly does the error message say?  (quote it)  Also, please make sure to post a [minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example

Comment: It says *what* object is const?

Comment: [Relevant question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217878/c-stl-set-update-is-tedious-i-cant-change-an-element-in-place).  The MCVE in it appears to be the best way to modify an element in a `std::set`.

Comment: [Another relevant question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340434/how-to-update-an-existing-element-of-stdset), declare mutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing anything to make the Student objects `const` accidentally.

---

## The Problem

Here is your problem: ([C++ documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/))

> All iterators in a set point to const elements.

In other words, a `set` will not allow you to modify elements through an iterator, even if the elements are not technically `const` otherwise.

So why is `set` defined that way? ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9600701/5029307))

> The elements of the set will be in sorted order. If you are allowed to
>   modify an element, then this sorting order can not be maintained.
>   Hence you can not modify the item.

---

## The Solution

You have one of three options.

### 1) Don't use `set`

Unless there is a very good (and very specific) reason you need to use `set`, then don't.  Use [`map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) instead.  It won't have this same restriction.

### 2) Remove and Insert

Remove the old element and insert the "updated" version of that element.  This takes O(1) time.  ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7340455/5029307))

### 3) Use `mutable`

If the data members that you want to modify are not involved in the natural ordering of the object type, then declare them to be `mutable`.  This is equivalent to saying that their value does not change the identity of a logically `const` instance of the class.  This will let you mutate those data members even in a `const` object or iterator  ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7340455/5029307))

Comment: Why don't you just write a complete answer before submitting?

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst Point #6 [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17250/346303)

Comment: I'm specifically referring to posting the answer when it's in a partial state. The link is correct, however I do not believe it's referring to your approach of streaming edits as you're literally typing them.

Comment: I thought it was something like that but I couldn't find anything that confirmed it. Thank you so much! I ended up going with the second option you suggested, and it works perfectly.